# Customer Uploaded Image Management Strategy in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

Our website is currently having a Custom Reviews functionality where customers can review the product and upload images (just like Amazon reviews)

We are currently saving the images in a separate SQL database which has Reviews table and Uploads table. Customer uploaded images are stored in binary format in SQL.

Now we are having a requirement where the customer has asked us to upload some 300-400 images with the campaign they did externally for a single product.

So when we are in the product page, these images are displayed in the reviews section.

What could be the best strategy going forward to manage the images? (as reviews are going to grow for every product)

1. Continue to save image in SQL DB as binary?
2. Move the images in Sitecore and save the path in SQL instead of
   Binary?
3. Migrating current images from SQL to Sitecore (publishing directly
   in Web DB in case of Production - we wrote a tool for it) Is this a correct practice to directly publish in web, since master is not present?

Answer (score 1):

By saying

> Move the images in Sitecore and save the path in SQL

i understand that your saying that you want to store them as File System, there are **Pros** and **Cons** in these two options, one of the **Cons** of storing the images in DB as binary is the size increase, but since you save your images in a separate database i would suggest to have images like any other item in the CMS and keep saving them in SQL DB as binary.

Here's a great [article](http://firebreaksice.com/storing-sitecore-media-in-the-database-vs-the-file-system/) that explains all this.